# How to pass a local file as input in spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark

How to pass a local file as input in spark-submit, I have tried like below:

```
spark-submit --jars /home/hduser/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/bundles/config-1.3.1.jar --class "retail.DataValidator" --master local[2] --executor-memory 2g --total-executor-cores 2 sample-spark-180417_2.11-1.0.jar file:///home/hduser/Downloads/Big_Data_Backup/ dev file:///home/hduser/spark-training/workspace/demos/output/destination file:///home/hduser/spark-training/workspace/demos/output/extrasrc file:///home/hduser/spark-training/workspace/demos/output/extradest
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: file:/home/inputfile , expected: hdfs://hadoop:54310
```

also tried path without the prefix "file://", but no luck. Its working fine in eclipse.

Thank you.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want those files be accessible by each executor you need to use option `files`. Example:

```
spark-submit --files file1,file2,file3
```

Comment: I tried this spark-submit --jars /home/hduser/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/bundles/config-1.3.1.jar --class "retail.DataValidator" --master local[2] --executor-memory 2g --total-executor-cores 2 --files /inputfileone,/outputfilepathone,/outputfilepathtwo,/outputfilepaththree sample-spark-180417_2.11-1.0.jar
but I got this error ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Added file file:file is a directory and recursive is not turned on.

Comment: when I tried in this order spark-submit --jars /home/hduser/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/bundles/config-1.3.1.jar --class "retail.DataValidator" --master local[2] --executor-memory 2g --total-executor-cores 2 sample-spark-180417_2.11-1.0.jar --files /inputfileone,/outputfilepathone,/outputfilepathtwo,/outputf‌​ilepaththree I got Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2